# Sending Data to Multiple Worksheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a master roster that has personnel assigned to different floors. In the master column for assigned floor, I would like the information to transfer to a separate worksheet dedicated to that floor, eight floors total with there own value ( 1 equals first floor worksheet, 2 equals second floor worksheet, and so on).

Name Contact Number Assigned Floor if assigned to floor five will move all previous information to the 5th floor worksheet.

If what I'm trying to do still sounds unclear let me know, but that's the best way to describe it. Would prefer not to use VBA, but if nothing else will appreciate full code layout.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the data? That's not very good data architecture. Enter all data in one sheet, then use another sheet to create a report that can be filtered by floor.

Comment: *will appreciate full code layout*...StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We help programmers who make earnest efforts. As is, this question is too broad.

Comment: Its how I was told to do it.

Comment: And I under stand its not a code writing service. I've been working on a vba code for it, but get stuck from time to time, so I figure to talk it out and see if there is a different avenue of approach i could use

Comment: Basically I'm working on it without any other real tech people I can bounce stuff off of. It helps me figure out problems when I can talk with other tech people and writers and see where my mistakes are at

Comment: lets see what vba code you have been working on

Comment: Can you provide images? For me it is difficult to follow you, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

```
Column A : Header in A1 = Country, A2:A? = Country names
Column B : Header in B1 = Name, B2:B? = Names
Column C : Header in C1 = Gender, C2:C? = F or M
Column D : Header in D1 = Birthday, D2:D? = Dates


1: Criteria in the code (=Netherlands, see the tips below the macro)
2: Filter on ActiveCell value
3: Filter on Range value (D1 in this example)
4: Filter on InputBox value

Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter1()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria :
    'This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    'Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Netherlands"

    'If you want to filter on a cell value you can use this, use "<>" for the opposite
    'This example uses the activecell value
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ActiveCell.Value

    'This will use the cell value from A2 as criteria
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Range("A2").Value

    ''If you want to filter on a Inputbox value use this
    'FilterCriteria = InputBox("What text do you want to filter on?", _
     '                              "Enter the filter item.")
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & FilterCriteria

    'Check if there are not more then 8192 areas(limit of areas that Excel can copy)
    CCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas:" _
             & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
             & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to worksheet"
    Else
        'Add a new Worksheet
        Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))

        'Ask for the Worksheet name
        sheetName = InputBox("What is the name of the new worksheet?", _
                             "Name the New Sheet")

        On Error Resume Next
        WSNew.Name = sheetName
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Change the name of sheet : " & WSNew.Name & _
                 " manually after the macro is ready. The sheet name" & _
                 " you fill in already exists or you use characters" & _
                 " that are not allowed in a sheet name."
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet
        My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With WSNew.Range("A1")
            ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
            ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
        End With

        ' If you want to delete the rows that you copy, also use this
        ' With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        '     On Error Resume Next
        '     Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
        '               .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '     On Error GoTo 0
        '     If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
        ' End With

    End If

    'Close AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    If Not WSNew Is Nothing Then WSNew.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

From this link.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_1.htm